# Late (runtime) addition of additional parent class possible?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

This is about multiple inheritance. Parent class A provides a few methods and B parent class B a few additional ones. By creating a class inheriting from A and B I could instantiate an object having both method sets.

Now my problem is, that I detect only after having instantiated A, that the methods from B would be helpful too (or more strictly stated, that my object is also of class B).

While

```
 aInstance.bMethod = types.MethodType(localFunction, aInstance)
```

works in principle, it has to be repeated for any bMethod, and looks unnecessary complicated. It also requires stand-alone (local) functions instead of a conceptually cleaner class B. Is there a more streamlined approach?

Update:
I tried abstract base class with some success, but there only the methods of one additional class could be added.

What I finally achieved is a little routine, which adds all top-level procedures of a given module:

```
from types import MethodType
from inspect import ismodule, isfunction, getmembers

# adds all functions found in module as methods to given obj
def classMagic(obj, module):
    assert(ismodule(module))
    for name, fn in getmembers(module, isfunction):
        if not name.startswith("__"):
            setattr(obj, name, MethodType(fn, obj))
```

Functionally this is sufficient, and I'm also pleased with the automatism, that **all** functions are processed and I don't have separate places of function definition and adding it as method, so maintenace is easy. The only remaining issue is reflected by the startswith line, as an example for a neccessary naming convention, if selected functions shall **not** be added.

Comment: how can you only know this at runtime? are you sure this is what you want to do?

Comment: also, it seems like you could use `__new__` to, depending on the values used when instantiating the object, return either an `A` object or an `(A, B)` object

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to add mixins to your class at run time. A very common way of adding mixins in Python is through decorators (rather than inheritance), so we can borrow this idea to do something runtime to the object (instead to the class).

I used `functools.partial` to freeze the `self` parameter, to emulate the process of binding a function to an object (i.e. turn a function into a method).

```
from functools import partial

class SimpleObject():
    pass

def MixinA(obj):
    def funcA1(self):
        print('A1 - propertyA is equal to %s' % self.propertyA)
    def funcA2(self):
        print('A2 - propertyA is equal to %s' % self.propertyA)
    obj.propertyA = 0
    obj.funcA1 = partial(funcA1, self=obj)
    obj.funcA2 = partial(funcA2, self=obj)
    return obj

def MixinB(obj):
    def funcB1(self):
        print('B1')
    obj.funcB1 = partial(funcB1, self=obj)
    return obj

o = SimpleObject()

# need A characteristics?
o = MixinA(o)

# need B characteristics?
o = MixinB(o)
```

Instead of `functools.partial`, you can also use `types.MethodType` as you did in your question; I think that is a better/cleaner solution.